# Program like NASA?: Margaret Hamilton's Three Primitive Control Structures

Tags: design, functional-programming, error-detection

On [slide 19 in a presentation](http://klabs.org/mapld04/presentations/session_s/8_s216_hamilton_s.ppt) Margaret Hamilton describes three primitive control structures. My goal is to reduce the probability of errors in my code by working with this "design framework". I am wondering if someone could explain to me how these structures work. Perhaps someone could point me to a simple implemented example in code.

Comment: recommended reading: **[On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)**

Comment: @gnat I am asking a question whether it is possible to implement the design principle X for a language of type Y. My question belongs to the category [“I would like others to explain ______ to me”](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). I welcome you explaining a down-vote, but your comment falls short of  addressing a specific issue.

Comment: Maybe of interest for you: Event Based programming & Flow Design: http://www.geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2011/03/19/flow-design-cheat-sheet-ndash-part-i-notation.aspx, looks very similar to me. That paradigm is simple to implement and works.

Comment: @DocBrown I don't think splits are pemissible unless tightly followed by "explicit join", include (I), or OR (O) and the document only states that joins (J) are preferable, not mandatory. I can definitely see the parallels. However, Hamilton's principles were developed with asynchronous events in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These three "primitive control structures" are ways to describe the ways in which a manager (superior) and two (or more) worker (subordinate) procedures coordinate their work.

The Join primitive shows that the manager calls A with some arguments, A returns some values, and then the manager calls B with A's results.  A's output parameter signature matches B's input parameter signature.

The Include primitive is essentially a scatter/gather technique.  The manager partitions the work between A and B, and gathers up the results.  The subordinates have different parameter signatures and do different things.

The Or primitive is a decision-making process in which one of the subordinates is chosen based on a partition function to select the child.  The subordinates have identical parameter signatures.

She is using these primitive design patterns to impose a very strict layered architecture on the software.

It helps to remember that the Apollo development program started, ran, and essentially ended *BEFORE* Dijkstra wrote "The Structure of the T.H.E Multiprogramming System", which laid out the fundamental concept of layered designs, and incidentally introduced semaphores for mutual exclusion.  Recall that Apollo 7, the first manned Apollo flight, was in 1968, and Apollo 17, the last Apollo flight to the moon, was in December 1972.

Comment: By scatter/gather, are you refering to Cutting and Tukey's method developed at the Xerox labs? Is there any open-source project that implements these primitives? I would like to look at more complex examples and see if I can tweak them for a functional programming language were I hope to remove most "interface errors" by designing the appropriate functional chains.

Comment: "Scatter/gather" is a very generic term these days.  In this case, I meant that the manager send some stuff to A and some other stuff to B, runs both A and B, and packages up the results from both of them.  "Scatter/gather" traditionally meant to take a large parallelizable task divide it up iinto pieces, "scatter" the pieces among several processors, then "gather" the individual results into one large object.  I know of no open-source project that implements these primitives, as this is work that was done in the mid-to-late 1960s.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the slide, its less a system of functions that returns multiple outputs and more a message passing system. If you write an object that can receive and return messages, it can return multiple outputs by simply returning multiple messages. In their case though, the messages that are returned are ordered, unlike most message-passing systems that are asynchronous, and the systems are built up in a strict tree structure. IT reminds me of a scenegraph.

Go look at message bus architectures for more information.

Comment: Hamilton developed the principles with asynchronous events in mind and requires inputs/outputs to be ordered. If I understand correctly, the mandatory ordering further contributes to the runtime integrity.